# What would the optimal march settings be for modern CPUs?

Tags: gcc

I seen a similar question on this, but it was specific to P4s and Core2s.  What I am looking for is a good setting for most modern CPUs, both AMD or Intel.  It seems to me that i686 is a little out of date.  I am leaning towards Pentium 4's for the extra SSE etc... instruction sets.  What is the best target that would be compatible with modern CPUs, both Intel or AMD, for either just -march or both -march and -mtune?

I'm currently using GCC 5.3.0 32 bit on Windows 7.

Comment: Why not sumply use `-march=pentium4`? You will have MMX, SSE and SSE2 instructio, set support. ;-)

Comment: That is what I am currently thinking about doing.  Not being extremely knowledgeable on different CPU architectures, I was just curious if there was something better that can be used which is still fairly universal.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "fairly universal" or "modern" CPUs. There are a lot of architectures available (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html), it's up to you to choose depending on whom you are targeting. ;-)